# AJAX w/ database - more than just a table

Tags: php, ajax, database

I'm using AJAX to update a table from a database. The table is great, that is what I was original after. But now I have a need for additional information from that database. I would like to collect the Lat & Long values and plot them in a map. I would also like to limit select options based on what is in the table. I thought about reproducing the query locally, but what a waste. How is the best way to do that? Thanks.

[ajax produced table](http://www.topofsteel.com/TestBed/Visitor_08.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the `latitute` and `longitude` values stored in the DB, you can do this.

1. Give the image an image map.
2. Translate the `latitute` and `longitude` values to suit the image's dimensions.
3. Position the map with those translated dimensions.
4. Give CSS Colouring or Background and also `title`.

To know about image maps: see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp) and [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/imagemap.shtml).

To know about CSS: see [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp).